# How to start new activity when click child in expandable listview (kotlin)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I created an expandable listview for my application but have some problems. I want to create a view button on each child list and when user click, it will open a new activity. I already try many ways but still stuck. please help me.

MainActivity.kt

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private lateinit var listViewAdapter: ExpandableListViewAdapter
private lateinit var chapterList: List<String>
private lateinit var topicList: HashMap<String, List<String>>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    showList()

    listViewAdapter = ExpandableListViewAdapter( context = this, chapterList, topicList)
    binding.eListView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter)


}

private fun showList() {

    chapterList = ArrayList()
    topicList = HashMap()

    (chapterList as ArrayList<String>).add("Sebelum Berlepas")
    (chapterList as ArrayList<String>).add("Setelah Sampai")
    (chapterList as ArrayList<String>).add("Sebelum Masuk Mekah")
    (chapterList as ArrayList<String>).add("Ketika di Kaabah")
    (chapterList as ArrayList<String>).add("Ketika Tawaf")
    (chapterList as ArrayList<String>).add("Keluar dari Mekah")
    (chapterList as ArrayList<String>).add("Sebelum Masuk Madinah")
    (chapterList as ArrayList<String>).add("Ketika di Masjid Nabawi")
    (chapterList as ArrayList<String>).add("Ketika di Raudhah")
    (chapterList as ArrayList<String>).add("Keluar dari Madinah")

    val topic1 : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    topic1.add("Doa Naik Kenderaan")
    topic1.add("Doa Keselamatan Diri dan Harta")
    topic1.add("Doa Dipermudahkan Urusan")

    val topic2 : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    topic2.add("Topic 1")
    topic2.add("Topic 2")
    topic2.add("Topic 3")

    val topic3 : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    topic3.add("Topic 1")
    topic3.add("Topic 2")
    topic3.add("Topic 3")

    val topic4 : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    topic4.add("Topic 1")
    topic4.add("Topic 2")
    topic4.add("Topic 3")

    val topic5 : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    topic5.add("Topic 1")
    topic5.add("Topic 2")
    topic5.add("Topic 3")

    val topic6 : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    topic6.add("Topic 1")
    topic6.add("Topic 2")
    topic6.add("Topic 3")

    val topic7 : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    topic7.add("Topic 1")
    topic7.add("Topic 2")
    topic7.add("Topic 3")

    val topic8 : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    topic8.add("Topic 1")
    topic8.add("Topic 2")
    topic8.add("Topic 3")

    val topic9 : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    topic9.add("Topic 1")
    topic9.add("Topic 2")
    topic9.add("Topic 3")

    val topic10 : MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    topic10.add("Topic 1")
    topic10.add("Topic 2")
    topic10.add("Topic 3")

    topicList[chapterList[0]] = topic1
    topicList[chapterList[1]] = topic2
    topicList[chapterList[2]] = topic3
    topicList[chapterList[3]] = topic4
    topicList[chapterList[4]] = topic5
    topicList[chapterList[5]] = topic6
    topicList[chapterList[6]] = topic7
    topicList[chapterList[7]] = topic8
    topicList[chapterList[8]] = topic9
    topicList[chapterList[9]] = topic10

}
```

}

ExpandableListViewAdapter.kt

```
override fun getGroupCount(): Int {
    return chapterList.size
}

override fun getChildrenCount(groupPosition: Int): Int {
    return this.topicsList.get(chapterList[groupPosition])!!.size
}

override fun getGroup(groupPosition: Int): Any {
    return chapterList[groupPosition]
}

override fun getChild(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Any {
    return this.topicsList[this.chapterList[groupPosition]]!![childPosition]
}

override fun getGroupId(groupPosition: Int): Long {
    return groupPosition.toLong()
}

override fun getChildId(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Long {
    return childPosition.toLong()
}

override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean {
    return false
}

override fun getGroupView(
    groupPosition: Int,
    isExpanded: Boolean,
    convertView: View?,
    parent: ViewGroup?
): View {

    var convertView = convertView
    val chapterTitle = getGroup(groupPosition) as String

    if(convertView==null) {

        val inflater =
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chapter_list, null)
    }


    val chapterTv = convertView!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.chapter_tv)
    chapterTv.setText(chapterTitle)
    val img = convertView.findViewById<View>(R.id.thumbnail) as ImageView
    val name = chapterTitle
    chapterTv.text = name

    //ASSIGN TEAM IMAGES ACCORDING TO TEAM NAME
    if (name === "Sebelum Berlepas") {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.sebelum)
    } else if (name === "Setelah Sampai") {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.sampai)
    } else if (name === "Sebelum Masuk Mekah") {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.mekah)
    } else if (name === "Ketika di Kaabah") {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.kaabah)
    } else if (name === "Ketika Tawaf") {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.tawaf)
    } else if (name === "Keluar dari Mekah") {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.mekah)
    } else if (name === "Sebelum Masuk Madinah") {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.madinah)
    } else if (name === "Ketika di Masjid Nabawi") {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.nabawi)
    } else if (name === "Ketika di Raudhah") {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.raudhah)
    } else if (name === "Keluar dari Madinah") {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.madinah)
    }


    return convertView
}

override fun getChildView(
    groupPosition: Int,
    childPosition: Int,
    isLastChild: Boolean,
    convertView: View?,
    parent: ViewGroup?
): View
{
    var convertView = convertView
    val topicTitle = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition) as String

    if(convertView==null) {

        val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.topics_list, null)
    }
    val topicTv = convertView!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.topics_tv)
    topicTv.setText(topicTitle)

    return convertView
}

override fun isChildSelectable(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Boolean {
    return true
}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="412dp"
    android:layout_height="467dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeNavi">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/eListView"
        android:layout_width="351dp"
        android:layout_height="407dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="31dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl">

    </ExpandableListView>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeNavi"
    android:layout_width="409dp"
    android:layout_height="213dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDoa"
        android:layout_width="161dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
        android:text="@string/doa"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/back_button"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/btn_back"
        tools:ignore="RedundantDescriptionCheck" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_nav"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/nav_button"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sidenav"
        tools:ignore="RedundantDescriptionCheck" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.116" />

    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="353dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/searchview_background"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:queryHint="Carian">

    </SearchView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

chapter_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chapter_tv"
        android:layout_width="255dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/chapter_textview"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/thumbnail"
        app:civ_border_color="#418434"
        app:civ_border_width="1dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sebelum"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

topics_list.xml

```
<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="View" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/topics_tv"
        android:layout_width="255dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
        android:text="@string/topics_tv"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_gravity="end"
        app:layout_row="0" />
</androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a button in your XML topics_list file.
Use it's click event to navigate to another activity.

```
override fun getChildView(
groupPosition: Int,
childPosition: Int,
isLastChild: Boolean,
convertView: View?,
parent: ViewGroup?): View{
var convertView = convertView
val topicTitle = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition) as String

if(convertView==null) {

    val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.topics_list, null)
}
val topicTv = convertView!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.topics_tv)
topicTv.setText(topicTitle)
val button = convertView!!.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
button.setOnClickListener(v-> {
 //navigate to your activity here
})

return convertView
```

}